# Jointly nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

We say that a matrix $J \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is nilpotent if $J^n = 0$. This is equivalent to the statement that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \quad \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $J^kx = 0$. What I would like to do is to extend this notion to pairs of matrices in the following way.

$J_1, J_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a nilpotent pair if $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \quad \exists N \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \{i_1,k_1,\ldots,i_N,k_N\} \in {\mathbb{Z}^+}^{2N}$$ such that $$J_1^{i_N}J_2^{k_N}\ldots J_1^{i_1}J_2^{k_1}x = 0$$

I am not sure if this definition makes sense. What I would like to ask is how one would attempt to characterize such a notion, i.e. what kind of properties the matrices $J_1,J_2$ should satisfy to be called a nilpotent pair. My apologies if this trivially follows from some existing result.

Comment: Why would that definition not make sense?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I thought I may have worded it poorly or in an imprecise way. This is some idea that popped into my head out of nowhere. I haven't seen it in a book or something so there is a chance that I am overlooking a crucial detail in the definition.

Comment: Definitions are judged according to whether they capture an idea. You should tell us what you want a «nilpotent pair» to be, and then we can tell if the definition matches that. As for characterizing the pairs satisfying the conditin you wrote, that looks rather impossible to me.

Comment: An idea is that if $J_1$ is invertible than $J_2$ is nilpotent.
This first consideration is in the mood of the following one.

Take a generalized  eigenspace $W_{\lambda}$ of $J_1$. If The is $k$ suck that $J_2^k(W_{\lambda})\subset W_0$ for all $\lambda \in \operatorname{Spec}(J_1)$ than $J_2, J_1$ is a nilpotent pair. This request is actually indispensable too.

Actually i do think you need just last 2 number need to be non-1.

Comment: A more standard notion would be that the ideal generated by $J_1$ and $J_2$ in the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb R)$ be nilpotent, or nil. I doubt your condition is equivalent to this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The idea that I want to capture was kind of implicit in the original post. Here I will make it explicit. For the case that there is only one matrix, nilpotency is equivalent to being able to map every vector to the origin after applying the mapping sufficiently many times. I wanted to extend nilpotency to pairs of matrices based on this notion. Would you be able to tell me why you think such a characterization is impossible? Does this problem reduce to some other problem, which is known to have no solution or not known to have a solution?

Comment: @Ivan I don't think that is true. Take $J_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $J_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: What is it a counterexample to?

Comment: @Ivan It is a counterexample to "if $J_1$ is invertible then $J_2$ is nilpotent". You can see that the example that I gave is a nilpotent pair.

Comment: I will just add this here as it may be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_spectral_radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple characterization indeed, very similar to what
exists for just one nilpotent matrix.

A pair $(J_1,J_2)$ is jointly nilpotent iff one of the products
$J_1^{i_N}J_2^{k_N}\ldots J_1^{i_1}J_2^{k_1}$ is the zero matrix.

Because if all those products are non-zero, then all their kernels
are strict subpaces of ${\mathbb R}^n$. So the union of all those
kernels (which is a countable union) cannot cover the
whole of ${\mathbb R}^n$ (for example it is nowhere dense
by the Baire category theorem).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to look into it a bit to convince myself. But I have a question. In the case of one nilpotent matrix it is sufficient to check the analogous condition up to the $n^{th}$ power where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix. But in the case of two matrices you have to do that for all $N$ and for all possible sequences $\{i_1,k_1,\ldots,i_N,k_N\}$. Is that true? If that is the case, then I cannot check the joint nilpotency of two matrices in finite time.

Comment: @Calculon as I find the question you just asked interesting, I put it in another MSE question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192450/large-product-of-matrices-equal-zero-but-not-small-ones

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: @Calculon Your question was recently answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193815/certain-products-of-mostly-diagonal-matrices-are-nonzero It might still be however that you have a different finite-time algorithm  to decide if matrices are jointly nilpotent