# Large product of matrices equal zero but not small ones

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra

Let $\cal F$ be a finite set of matrices in the same ${\cal M}_n({\mathbb R})$
for some fixed $n$. Following the ideas in [that recent MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187337/jointly-nilpotent-matrices/1192068?noredirect=1#comment2427585_1192068), let us say that
$\cal F$ is **jointly nilpotent** if some finite product
of elements in $\cal F$ is zero, i.e. if $C_1C_2\ldots C_r=0$
for some $r$ and some $C_i\in{\cal F}$. The smallest such $r$ is called
the nilpotency index of $\cal F$. I denote by $m(t)$ the largest
nilpotency index of a jointly nilpotent $t$-element set (note that $m(t)$ might be infinite).

Obviously $m(1)=n$. What are the other values of $m(t)$ for $t\geq 2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193815/certain-products-of-mostly-diagonal-matrices-are-nonzero) shows that $m(2)=\infty$, and therefore that $m(t)=\infty$ for any $t\geq 2$.