# References required for "minimal switches to control a switched linear system"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, optimal-control

A switched linear system of ODEs is defined as a system of ODEs of the form $\dot{x}(t) = A_i(t)x(t)$ , with $A_i$ for $i=1,2,...,N$ being a fixed number of matrices. More precisely, given a $\sigma : [0,t] \to \{1,2,...,N\}$ and an initial point $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb R^n$,we could talk about (assuming existence and uniqueness of solution) the solution to $\dot{x}(t) = A_{\sigma(t)}x(t)$ with $x(0) = \mathbf x$, and look at its trajectory.

In the research of switched linear systems, often problems of controllability(See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability)) are considered. Other topics of research include minimizing , among all $\sigma$ suitable (e.g. steering to a certain point/region), a quadratic functional of $\sigma$.

---

However, I am not aware of any research looking at the *minimum* number of switches to reach a point/region.

More precisely, consider a fixed $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$, a destination region $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbf x \notin S$, a fixed $T>0$ (think of $T$ as being very large) and let $$\Sigma = \{\sigma : [0,T] \to \{1,2,...,N\}, \text{ The solution  of $\dot{x}(t) = A_{\sigma(t)}x(t)$ reaches $S$ before time $T$}\}$$

Assume that $\Sigma$ is non-empty. Now, for each $\sigma \in \Sigma$, the number of times it switches is its number of discontinuities, so define $D(\sigma) = n$ if $\sigma$ has $n$ discontinuities, and $D(\sigma) = \infty$ if $\sigma$ has infinitely many discontinuities.

Is there literature available on studying $\min_{\sigma \in \Sigma}D(\sigma)$?

In words : *Assuming there is a control steering $\mathbf x$ to $S$, there is a control with at most $\_\_\_$ switches also steering $\mathbf x$ to $S$*.

I would like to know if there are papers/textbooks which discuss this exact question, in the context of linear switched systems. I am aware of Pontryagin's maximum principle, but do not know how it would provide structural results for this question, so if anybody could suggest an approach via PMP I would be happy as well.

Comment: I think you should rather look into dynamic programming.  PMP is not likely to bring you any further regarding the switching structure.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187337/jointly-nilpotent-matrices

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you for your reply. I shall attempt dynamic programming. But the point is that I need a structural theorem of the kind I mentioned. While DP can help me solve a specific problem, will I be able to use it to write theorems? I have seen it being done (e.g. with monotone operators etc. coming into play) but over there the structure is not of a switched linear system but rather of an *ordinary* linear system which is easier to analyse. But thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Calculon Thank you for the question. It does have a similarity to the question I ask because I too expect to consider products of matrices of the form $e^{A_it_i}$ for $t_i$ being positive real numbers, but what I search for is whether the ranges of these intersect $S$ for a certain product, and what is the minimal number of matrices involved in that product. I will still look into the kernel stabilizing property, it should be giving me some structure on the problem. Thank you.